# How to transform some Blaze `Html` before rendering it with Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod, blaze-html

I have some HTML entered by the user which is displayed in a Yesod template. I would like to transform this HTML, stripping out `style` attributes from it before it gets rendered, but i cannot find out how.

If my template contains `#{ html }` i can pass `html` as a value through a function simply writing `#{ transform html }`, if the `transform` function has a signature: `transform :: Html -> Html` where `Html` is the type defined by `blaze-html` [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-html-0.8.1.1/docs/Text-Blaze-Html.html). The problem i see is that Blaze does not seem to expose functionalities useful in order to walk an HTML tree, or even just get the descendents of a given `Html`. So which strategies would you suggest? Should i try to get into the Blaze internals?

I am not sure whether this should be considered purely an issue with Blaze. Transforming `Html` elements is not one of the main use cases of Blaze, so this problem needs to be tackled in the context of rendering with Yesod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to render to Text or ByteString first, blaze provides no means of analyzing content. Then you can process the data with a library like html-conduit or tagsoup (which is what [xss-sanitize](http://www.stackage.org/package/xss-sanitize) does).

Comment: Thanks, this makes me think that performing this kind of transformation when the page is rendered is a bad idea. I should rather sanitise this content before storing it in the database